# Blurry Evee Render especially at the edges of model even though rendering at 500 samples?

Tags: rendering, light, eevee-render-engine, blur

Render looks blurry especially at the edges,just with a very little zoom in, even though render samples in EVEE are set to 500 .

[image]

Comment: Did you check the camera's aperture settings?

Comment: I tried even with DOF turned off without and also with DOF turned on , tweaked aperture settings but didn't seem to work